# Gmail - Archive email with imap

Tags: php, gmail, imap

How can I archive an email in gmail with imap using php?

I can move an email to another folder with:

```
imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number, "AnotherFolder");
```

But, I'm trying:

```
imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number, "Archive");
```

And the email does not move. I also tried "[Gmail]\Archive".

Comment: Does it return false?

Comment: In Gmail, archiving corresponds to removing all the tags.  If you want to just archive it from the current folder, a standard delete suffices (rather than a move to trash)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Max is correct. In Gmail's pseudo-IMAP, deleting a message means archiving it.

Just a slight optimisation if you have many emails to archive - `imap_delete()` one-by-one takes a long time. Use `imap_setflag_full()` instead - which allows you to specify message sequences: lists (delimited by a comma), ranges (delimited by a colon) and probably a combination of both - with the IMAP function's flag parameter set to '\Deleted'. I always use UIDs - unique message ids - instead of the message numbers that are returned by default. I cannot remember the reason why now - perhaps it is more reliable? If you are using UIDs, note that PHP's options constant is different for different IMAP functions, e.g. for `imap_search()` it is `SE_UID` and for `imap_setflag_full()` it is `ST_UID`.

`imap_mail_move()` also lets you specify message sequences and as @Max stated, it is the way to move emails to Trash/Bin: set the `$mailbox` parameter to `[Gmail]/Trash` or `[Gmail]/Bin` depending on jurisdiction. Double check the correct mailbox using `imap_list($imap, '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}', '*');`.

`imap_expunge()` is probably unnecessary since in the Gmail web app > ⚙ > See all settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > under "IMAP access", auto-expunge seems to be the default setting.

One last thing, which should be very obvious, but I will include in case it saves anyone a lot of head scratching. I started working with PHP IMAP and Gmail again after a long time and reused a previous script I wrote, forgetting I had set the read-only flag `OP_READONLY` when making the initial connection. The IMAP errors produced should have made things obvious, but interestingly, moving emails to Trash worked despite the errors and being in read-only mode; so I assumed the errors were due to some Gmail oddities. But for "deleting" emails, i.e. archiving emails, you need to make sure you are not connected in read-only mode.